# Como agrupar palabras por sus raíces semánticas

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

Estoy trabajando con un conjunto de palabras la cuales hay algunas que son de la misma familia de palabras, por ejemplo:

```
lista = ['inteligencia','casa','inteligentemente','caseta','historiador',...]
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que mediante una función la cual me extrae la raíz semántica de las palabras que le pase, me agrupe las palabras que tengan la misma raíz. Por ejemplo, las raíces de las palabras anteriores serían:

```
inteligencia -> intel
casa -> cas
inteligentemente -> intel
caseta -> cas
historiador -> hist
```

Entonces el resultado que me debería quedar es que me agrupe las palabras que tengan la misma raíz en una lista, para que así si se van añadiendo palabras con la misma raíz se vayan añadiendo en esas listas:

```
Raíz intel: ['inteligencia','inteligentemente']
Raíz cas: ['casa','caseta']
Raíz hist: ['historiador']
```

Lo que he intentado ha sido lo siguiente:

```
def group(keyword):
   kw_list = [keyword]
   group = ''

   for k in range(0, len(kw_list)):
        if k == 0:
            group = stemmer(kw_list[k])
        elif stemmer(kw_list[k]) == stemmer(kw_list[k - 1]):
            group = kw_list[k - 1]
        else:
            group = stemmer(kw_list[k])
   return res
```

La función de stemmer() es la que me devuelve la raíz de las palabras.

No sé si voy muy bien encaminado, pero no consigo el resultado que necesito. ¿Cómo podría agrupar esas palabras?.

Gracias.

Comment: De que modulo o función proviene `stemmer`?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que la función `group` debería recibir una lista de palabras. No entiendo qué significa entonces el argumento `keyword` que declaras.

Por otro lado la mayoría de lo que haces dentro de esa función no tiene mucho sentido. De entrada haces esta asignación:

```
   kw_list = [keyword]
```

con lo que acabas de crear una lista llamada `kw_list` que contiene un solo elemento (que es el argumento recibido por la función). Así que el bucle for que haces después iterará una sola vez, ya que `kw_list` tiene un solo elemento. Si lo que querías era iterar por los elementos de la lista recibida deberías haber hecho `kw_list = keyword`, sin los corchetes. O ya directamente prescindir de `kw_list` y usar `keyword`.

Por otro lado tu forma de "agrupar" no funciona porque parece presuponer que todas las palabras de un mismo grupo semántico han de aparecer seguidas en la lista que recibes, y no veo por qué habría de ser así.

En todo caso, asignas a la veriable `group` el grupo semántico al que pertenecería la palabra, pero no usas después la variable `group` para nada. Y lo que es peor, retornas `res` que es una variable que hasta ese momento no se había mencionado y por tanto está indefinida.

Creo que lo que buscas es crear un diccionario en el que las claves serían las raíces semáticas y los valores serían listas con las palabras que tienen esa raiz.

Esto lo puedes construir así:

```
def group(lista):
  res ={}
  for palabra in lista:
    stem = stemmer(palabra)
    if stem not in res:    # Si es la primera palabra con esta raiz
      res[stem] = []       # creamos para ella una entrada en el diccionario
    res[stem].append(palabra)  # Añadimos esa palabra a esa entrada del diccionario
  return res
```

Al ejecutarlo con tu lista de ejemplo daría este resultado:

```
{'cas': ['casa', 'caseta'],
 'hist': ['historiador'],
 'intel': ['inteligencia', 'inteligentemente']}
```

### Versión más compacta

Usando la clase `defaultdict` puedes especificar un tipo de diccionario cuyos contenidos sean por defecto listas, de modo que sean creados "sobre la marcha" cuando se intenta acceder a ellos. Esto permite simplificar el código:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def group(lista):
  res = defaultdict(list)
  for palabra in lista:
    res[stemmer(palabra)].append(palabra)
  return res
```